# How to find the value of x?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, arithmetic

I was trying to find the value of X for an hour now but don't know how to start and I don't know why A= 42.9cm2. I mean wasn't A supposed to be 16.5cm2.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Divide the figure into three rectangles: A top part, a middle part and a bottom part. What are the areas of the top and bottom parts together? What area do you need the middle part to be?

Caution: Note that the lengths are in mm, and the area in cm<sup>2</sup>.